# Best way to automatically decode bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I am using the following (works in both Py2 and 3)

```
if isinstance(string, bytes):
    string = string.decode('utf-8')
```

However, is there a better way to do this that is both Python 2 and 3 compatible. Seems like I missed something obvious. In python 2 it would be as simple as `str(string)`

EDIT:

**Context**: I am making a library/util class accepts a Redis client object. This object has an option to automatically decode responses (default off), or return plain bytes. So given a response from this object, it can be either bytes or str depending on how the object was configured

Comment: I think the right answer to this question depends on the context, why are you comparing bytes object to a string?

Comment: The context here is redis, the python library returns bytes as it has no encoding information

Comment: Realised my question was a bit confusing; cleaned it up

Comment: @nehz I've updated my answer based on the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to avoid the problem in the first place. Use the ["unicode sandwich" technique](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#35) - convert your data to strings quickly after you read it, and convert it back to bytes only when you need to serialize it. If you do this, then you shouldn't end up with an object that might be strings or might be bytes, so you shouldn't ever need to detect whether it has been decoded yet or not.

---

If you *really* can't do that for some reason (if some third-party code could hand you either based on conditions you don't control), then the next easiest thing is to use the library `six`, which makes it easier to write code that works in both Python 2 and Python 3. Among other things, it has a variable called [`six.binary_type`](http://pythonhosted.org//six/#six.binary_type), which is `bytes` in Python 3 and `str` in Python 2 making it possible to modify your existing technique to:

```
if isinstance(string, six.binary_type):
    string = string.decode('utf-8')
```

Note that, in Python 2, `str(string)` does *not* give you the same type of object - it gives you a `str`, which fills the same role as Python 3's `bytes`. You would actually want `unicode(string, 'utf-8')`, but you might as well just use `decode` since it has the same name in both.

Comment: thanks for the tip about this compat library, will save me avoiding certain constructs because its not py2/3 compatible

Comment: @eryksun quite true. I have rephrased that part of my answer.